# Pronunciación anormal de "ahí" en "vete por ahí"

Tags: pronunciación

El "**ahí**" de "vete por ahí" parece pronunciarse de dos formas diferentes:

- Cuando se utiliza para indicar una dirección, se pronuncia correctamente, como palabra aguda.
- Cuando se utiliza como interjeción se suele pronunciar sin acentuar, como si fuera "hay" en vez de "ahí".

¿Por qué esa anomalía en el habla?

Comment: Como andaluz, me siento identificado con esa pronunciación. Sin embargo, debo preguntar dónde la has oído, ya que tal vez debamos ceñir la respuesta a dicha región.

Comment: En el norte de Mexico, especificamente en Monterrey, sucede este fenomeno de pronunciar el "ahi" como si fuera un "hay" al decir "vete por ahi" "esta por ahi"

Comment: Es habitual oírlo en regiones donde el nivel educativo es relativamente bajo. Ignoro el por qué.

Comment: Yo he oído la expresión en toda España y siempre pronunciada de la forma que dice la pregunta. Es más, si digo que *he estado por ahí*, también pronunciaré de la misma forma.

Comment: @Gorpik ciertamente, parece que la pronunciación /ái/ depende más de la frase en la que vaya que de la localización o el nivel educativo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la [Nueva Gramática Española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica), curiosamente, viene recogido este fenómeno en el [epígrafe 17.8j](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bngyAUzzJRAhWklI):

> En las construcciones que se acaban de mencionar ["por ahí"] es habitual que *ahí* se pronuncie como diptongo: /ái/. También se pronuncia de esta manera en otras construcciones en las que *ahí* es adverbio de lugar, pero aparece integrado en fórmulas lexicalizadas o semilexicalizadas. La expresión *ahí está* se usa para enfatizar en el diálogo alguna declaración previa; *vete por ahí* se emplea en el habla coloquial como fórmula imprecativa; *ahí ahí* se usa con el sentido de "aproximadamente igual(es)" [...].

Es decir, se pronuncia /ái/ cuando el adverbio pierde su sentido literal de "en ese sitio", o cuando dicho significado no es totalmente relevante, y se integra dentro de otras expresiones. Así, en *vete por ahí*, lo importante no es adónde te vayas, sino simplemente que te vayas, y al perder importancia el adverbio se acaba pronunciando "vete porái".

Comment: Se me ocurre que, aunque en este caso la palabra *ahí* no sea átona, puede ser un fenómeno paralelo al que se da con la expresión *ahí mismo*, que frecuentemente se pronuncia *ai-MIS-mo*, como si fuera una sola palabra; al perder el acento, el hiato se rompe y no queda más remedio que pronunciar como diptongo.

Comment: @Carlos Alejo: ese epígrafe simplemente describe el hecho, pero seguimos sin saber la causa

Comment: @user13560 la causa, como yo lo entiendo, es que se usa un adverbio de lugar en una frase en la que dicho adverbio pierde su sentido literal o su importancia dentro de la frase, y entonces el hablante no se molesta en pronunciarlo correctamente, relajando el habla.